# Displaying a WPF dialog from the main thread in a .NET library

Tags: wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0, process, dispatcher

I've read several posts here and via references from google, but haven't come up with the proper solution.

I have an assembly that displays a dialog, but that dialog needs to be shown from the main thread.  The caller could be a .NET application or native application.

Conceptually, it seems like I simply need to get the application's main thread ID, and then call `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread( main_thread_id_here)` to get the Dispatcher, and then call `Invoke` to display my dialog from the main thread.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to get the main thread ID.

My next approach was to (following advice from another SO question) iterate over `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads`, and get the thread ID of the `ProcessThread` that was started first.  But now that I have this `ProcessThread`, I don't have a way to get the corresponding `Thread` object.  I figured that I could next get a list of all running .NET threads in the current process, and compare their thread IDs via `GetHashCode` to determine which one is the main thread.  I could then use `FromThread` to get the `Dispatcher`... but I haven't been able to find any information on retrieving anything but `ProcessThreads`!

Does anyone have tips on how to solve this problem using either approach I have explained above, or maybe another approach?  Please keep in mind that I don't have control over the calling application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // Show dialog
}));
```

You could also grab the dispatcher from the `Window.Dispatcher` property.

Comment: I've tried this before in the past, and I recall that it doesn't work because Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher doesn't necessarily give you the main thread.  It could very well give you a worker thread.  IIRC, if you request a Dispatcher from a thread that doesn't yet have one, one is automatically created and returned.

Comment: Updated the post to `Application.Current.Dispatcher`. This way works for me; I had remembered a different way originally. If this still doesn't work for whatever reason, you can just take a Dispatcher object from one of your `Window`s.

Comment: Ok, awesome, that works for my .NET test app.  Dumb question -- will it work the same even if the caller is a native app?

Comment: As long as you've made the transition to managed code it should work just fine. I think I've actually done this in one of my apps.

Comment: And what if it is a Console App ?

Comment: Sure :) But if to talk about SUBJ (how to get main thread) without WPF. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: @Grigory You could ask another question. This one is about WPF.

Comment: This is not the answer to the OP's question. Either the question of his post should bechanged, or this answer should.